# Is There a DRYer Way of Handling Events with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a dryer way of doing the following as I am repeating `onMouseOver` several times:

```
const [color, setColor] = useState()


return(
  <ul>
    <li onMouseOver={() => { setColor("red") }>List Item</li>
    <li onMouseOver={() => { setColor("blue") }>List Item</li>
    <li onMouseOver={() => { setColor("orange") }>List Item</li>
    <li onMouseOver={() => { setColor("green") }>List Item</li>
  </ul>
)
```

With JavaScript, outside of React, you can use `getElementsByTag` and iterate through that. Since React doesn't allow you do work with the DOM in that manner, what options is there to clean up this code?

Comment: First, `setColor` is a function, you'd want to call it: `setColor('red')`

Answer (score 1):

You can still iterate over stuff in React, you just need to programmatically build your components rather than programmatically modify them.

Consider something like this:

```
const colors = ["red", "blue", "orange", "green"];

return (
  <ul>
    {colors.map(color => (
      <li
        key={color}
        onMouseOver={() => {
          setColor = color;
        }}
      >
        List Item
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

Although note that you probably want your handler to be *calling* `setColor` like `setColor(color)` rather than assigning to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [color, setColor] = useState()
const colors = ["red", "blue", "orange", "green"]
return (
    <ul>
        {colors.map((c, i) => <li key={i} value={c} onMouseOver={(e) => setColor(e.target.value) }>{c}</li>)}
    </ul>
)
```